# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority for prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, spring-boot-actuator

I was trying to monitor one of our Spring boot application using Prometheus but unfortunately the status of this service is not getting UP in ubuntu server, it’s showing some error like –

/prometheus: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority, Where from my local Prometheus this service is UP and also able to monitor some of the http requests.
[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLfrH.png)

Comment: I't seems like your server is running with self signed certificate so when prometheus try to call it it's failing on certificate issue.
Yiou can:
Install your certificate in prometheus server.

Or tell prometheus to ignore ssl verification.
(by the way you can lose the port number in the url https default is 443)

Answer (score 14):

I have faced the same issue.
Solved it by:

Configure Prometheus to ignore ssl verification as suggested by @Shmuel

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'prometheus'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'job-name'

    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - host_name_or_ip_address1
        - host_name_or_ip_address2
        - host_name_or_ip_address2

    scheme: https  # to use https instead of http for scraping

    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true  # This is the key
```

Comment: Should we create multiple jobs for different applications or a single job with multiple targets, each target pointing to different applications? what is the better way?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a self-signed certificate you can add the certificate to the `scrape_configs` under `tls_config`:

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'prometheus'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'job-name'

    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - host_name_or_ip_address1

    tls_config:
      ca_file: /path/to/prometheus.crt

    scheme: https
```